# Mixed chapter numbering (e.g. Chapter 1a, Chapter 1b, Chapter 2 ...)

Tags: chapters

I'm stitching 4 research papers using the `book` class. The first two papers are closely related, so I would like the chapter labelling to be as following:

- Chapter 1a
- Chapter 1b
- Chapter 2
- Chapter 3

Is there a way to achieve this mixed numbering with some LaTeX variant?

Answer (score 1):

By redefining `\thechapter` and altering the value of counter `chapter`, the following example works, though not very elegant.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{1\alph{chapter}}
\chapter{title}

\chapter{title}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\chapter{title}

\chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

[image]